# get_json_object with path based on row?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like this:

```
row  | key   |  json
0    | a     |  {'something':{'a':1}}
1    | b     |  {'something':{'a':2, 'b':3 }}
```

And I would like to retrieve for the values in the json defined in the `key` column:

```
row | value
0   | 1 // from $.something.a
1   | 3 // from $.something.b
```

on hive one can do

```
select get_json_object(json, concat("$.something.", key) from table;
```

and it would return the proper value. However, on pyspark, I didn't find a way to replicate this behaviour, it doesn't seem to be able to build the path base on the column. I tried

```
context.table("table").select(
    get_json_object(F.col("json", concat("$something.", F.col("key"))
);
```

and it tells me "Column is not iterable". However, using just concat works fine:

```
context.table("table")
 .select(
    concat("$something.", F.col("key").alias(path)
 );

row | path
0   | $.something.a
1   | $.something.b
```

I was able to do it using an UDF, but is there any way to acomplish this with PySpark out of the box?

Comment: `get_json_object` takes a String as a second argument... You're giving it a Column by calling `concat()`

Comment: I am aware of that. But how can I pass a string based on the row?  That is my question.

Comment: It's an expensive operation and generally not preferred but you can iterate over rows and apply a function using `df.flatmap` or `df.foreach`.

Comment: Have you tried just string concatenating? `"$.something." + F.col("key")`?

Comment: I ended up using sql for that, and the Hive version of get_json_object

Comment: @RahulChawla why it is expensive operation any references, special cases of reasoning for same.?

Answer (score 2):

The current spark implementation does not provide a way to pass the second argument as column in `get_json_object` (although internally it converts that to a literal column and uses it.)

I used a UDF to achieve the same thing:

I have input JSONs, and the path of field I am interested in (which can be different for each JSON) is coming from a different file.

Created a UDF which takes two paramaters (the JSON column and the path column) and returns the string value at that path in JSON.
`

```
def getValueFromJson = (json: String, path: String) => {

    def getValue(json: JsonNode, strings: Array[String], index: Int): String = {
      if (index < strings.length - 1)
        getValue(json.path(strings(index).trim), strings, index + 1) //1 //0
      else
        json.path(strings(index).trim).toString
    }

    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    val root: JsonNode = mapper.readTree(json) //c.b
    val strings = path.split('.')
    val value = getValue(root, strings, 0)
    value
  }
```

Usage of the UDF:

```
    val a = "{ \"id\": 1, \"b\": \"in 1\" }"
    val b = "{ \"id\": 2, \"c\": {  \"b\": \"in 2\" } }"
    val c = "{ \"id\": 3, \"b\": \"in 3\" }"
    val d = "{ \"id\": 4, \"f\": {  \"a\": \"in 4\" } }"

    val ll = List(a, b, c, d)
    val path = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").load("paths.csv")

    import spark.implicits._
    val ip = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(ll).toDF

    val ipWithId = ip.withColumn("id", get_json_object(col("value"), "$.id").cast("integer"))

    val joined = ipWithId.join(path, Seq("id"))

    val getValFromJson = spark.udf.register("getjson", getValueFromJson)

    val finalDf = joined.withColumn("valfromJson", getValFromJson(col("value"), col("path")))

    finalDf.show(false)
```

Where Path.csv is this:

```
id,path
1, b
2, c.b
3, b
4, f.a
```

And this is the output:

```
+---+----------------------------------+----+-----------+
|id |value                             |path|valfromJson|
+---+----------------------------------+----+-----------+
|1  |{ "id": 1, "b": "in 1" }          | b  |"in 1"     |
|2  |{ "id": 2, "c": {  "b": "in 2" } }| c.b|"in 2"     |
|3  |{ "id": 3, "b": "in 3" }          | b  |"in 3"     |
|4  |{ "id": 4, "f": {  "a": "in 4" } }| f.a|"in 4"     |
+---+----------------------------------+----+-----------+
```